# How to setVisibility of a TextView in a Dialogue Box, called from outside the MainActivity Thread?

Tags: android

I have a textview in a dialogue box and I want to toggle the visibility from a class which is outside the MainActivity Thread.

In the MainActivity,I have the Dialog box:

```
addDevDialogue = new Dialog(this);
addDevDialogue.setContentView(R.layout.add_device_dialogue);

public void addDeviceDialogue ()
  {
    addDevDialogue.setTitle("Add SAndTerm Device:");
    addDevDialogue.setCancelable(false);
    addDevDialogue.show();

    incorrectIP = (TextView)addDevDialogue.findViewById(R.id.rongtxt);
    incorrectIP.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }
```

And I have another class where if a particular condition meets, I want to change the visibility of the TextView which is in the dialogue box.
For reference sake I ll put up the class from where I want to toggle the visibility.

The Class:

```
public class IP_Validation {

  Context contxt;

  public IP_Validation(Context context)
   {
     contxt = context;
   }
  public void change_state()
   {
      //toggle the TextView Visibility from here
   }
 }
```

Could you tell me a proper way to access the textview from a class which is outside the MainActivity?

Comment: I would refer storing the state in sharedPreference and not in the class

Comment: @SwarnanEel add the textview as a parameter in your method inside of your class and change its state like this `public void change_state(TextView view)`

Answer (score 0):

In your activity in onCreate create new object:

```
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TestNonActivityClass test = new TestNonActivityClass(textView);
    test.doSomething();
```

Next, create constructor in your nonActivity class, like this:

```
public class TestNonActivityClass {


    private TextView textViewInNonActivityClass; //textview

    public TestNonActivityClass(TextView textView){ //constructor
        this.textViewInNonActivityClass = textView;
    }


    public void changeText(){ //some method..
        textViewInNonActivityClass.setText("Changed");
        textViewInNonActivityClass.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

If you change state of textViewInNonActivityClass, it should change on the screen..

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a handler in your Activity

   ```
   Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == 1){
               // set toggle visible or whatever
            }
        }
   }
   ```
2. Pass the handler to your IP_Validation

   ```
   Handler handler;
   public IP_Validation(Context context , Handler handler)
   {
       contxt = context;
       this.handler = handler;
   }
   ```
3. When you need to change the visibility , use

   ```
   handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest form of solution would to make this change:

```
public void addDeviceDialogue ()
  {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            addDevDialogue.setTitle("Add SAndTerm Device:");
            addDevDialogue.setCancelable(false);
            addDevDialogue.show();

            incorrectIP = (TextView)addDevDialogue.findViewById(R.id.rongtxt);
            incorrectIP.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        });
  }
```

and call the method like this:

```
  public void change_state()
   {
      ((MainActivity) context).addDeviceDialogue();
   }
```